# recurrence relation involving big O notation

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

The solution of the recurrence relation T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n^2) is given as Big theta of n^2.

How do we get this solution.

The way I solved it :- the height of the recurrence tree is logn. And we have at each step n^2 complexity. SO recurrence relation is O(n^2 logn).

How do we get answer in Big theta in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to ["Master Theorem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).

Your problem falls into [Case 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Case_3) of the theorem, so according to its conclusion, the complexity is `Θ(n^2)`.

Comment: So is it also equal to O(n^2logn) ?

Comment: @user2753551 It is `O(n^2logn)`, but not `Θ(n^2logn)`. The big theta defines a more accurate complexity, while big o defines something like  an upper bound.